# System audit of hardened device regarding certificate handling

Tags: network, certificates, man-in-the-middle, audit, operating-systems

I am tasked with auditing the default configuration (system configuration, default applications...) that is set for some computers before they are given to users.

Though I have never seen it anywhere, I feel it would make sense to check whether all its applications that use the network (internal or external) are properly configured to refuse invalid certificates (at least self-signed). In order to achieve that, I was thinking I would boot one such computer in its target network, but with a MITM device that provides self-signed certificates, and basically "launch" all installed applications (OS ones, corporate self-made, corporate tools such as chat or mail or antivirus, ...) and "see" (if they keep working despite having been presented an invalid certificate) whether the app still works and I can thus decrypt traffic on my MITM device.

First of all, is it a good thing to check? And secondly, is my approach to detect it correct, or are there better/faster ones?

Comment: What change would you make if it failed the test? You seem to assume that apps have something to configure in this regard.

Comment: Well yes, if it's a configuration issue, then fix it, otherwise if it's a corporate-owned app, fix it, otherwise if it's an 3rd party app, contact the app vendor (opensource or company) and have them fix it, and if all else fails consider switching to an alternative that offers better security ; though I don't really understand the point of your question : are you implying that this whole approach is useless because no meaningful action can be taken from this extra knowledge ?

Comment: Your stated goal is to ***audit*** the hardening configuration. That means you are confirming the expected result of the configuration. But do your apps have a configuration regarding cert checking? I'm saying that your entire activity in this might not be relevant. And then, if relevant, possibly not actionable. What it sounds like you **want** to do is to find a problem that the hardening process didn't account for. But that's not an audit.

Comment: okay, I used the wrong term then sorry, but what I want is indeed what you stated.

Comment: Ok, then you are chasing "unknown unknowns". That *can* be ok, but are these tests relevant? Have you confirmed that the apps have something you can change if you find an issue? You've asked if this is a "good thing to check". If the check is irrelevant, then it isn't, regardless of the security implications.

Comment: If the only parameter to figure out if the check is relevant is to make sure I will be able to do something about it if something is found, then as I stated in my first comment, I will be one way or another. Depending on the app (whether internally developped or not, ...), the solution could be to fix it internally or go as far as switching to an alternative.

Comment: Then that's not an audit of the "default configuration". I'm not trying to be pedantic here, but the way you have framed the question does not appear to accurately reflect what you've been tasked to do, which is making the question confusing. And you appear to have answered your own question. If how apps respond to invalid certificates is something that you are wanting to check (whether it is 'good' or not) then offering invalid certs is a valid check. TLS interception is a well-known process and there are many ways to do it.

Comment: So, what this question seems to boil down to is: how can I perform a TLS intercept? There are numerous methods to accomplish this.